# Approximating higher dimensional Lipschitz maps with differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f:[0,1]^n \to {\mathbb R}$ is Lipschitz. It is known that $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere. Can we construct a sequence $f_n$ of continuously differentiable functions such that $\lim f_n=f$ in the sup norm and $\lim f_n'(x) =f'(x)$ whenever $f'(x)$ exists?

For $n=1$, one can try to obtain a solution by taking $g_n$ with $\int_0^1|f'-g_n|<1/n$ and defining $f_n$ by $f_n(x)=\intop_0^x g_n(x) dx +f(0)$. But even in this simple case, we only get $\lim f_n'(x) =f'(x)$ almost everywhere.

Comment: It should be enough to take $f_n=f\star g_n$ where $g_n$ is a suitable kernel (non negative, smooth and concentrated). I'd give a try to the Jackson's kernel.

Comment: Thanks, but I had already tried convolution with the standard sequence of bump functions (constructed from a mollifier), but this only gives convergence in the sup norm of the sequence of c^\infty functions and not the convergence of the sequence of the derivatives of the functions to the derivative of the Lipschitz function when the latter exists. The problem is that the derivative of the Lipschitz function does not in general satisfy any continuity property. I cannot think why it would be different with any other kernel, unless you know something about Jackson's kernel that I do not know.